# Change hyperlink text color after page is rendered

Tags: php, jquery, html, hyperlink

I am changing the color of a link after it is selected. The color is changing, but when the selected page is rendered it returns to the default color.

php pages look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<?php
    $Page = "Contact";

    include 'header.php';
?>

<body>

    <?php
        include "facebook.php";
    ?>

    <?php
        include "headers.php";
    ?>

    <?php
        include "navBar.php";
    ?>

    <?php
        include "containers.php";
    ?>

    <?php
        include "footer.php";
    ?>

</body>

</html>
```

navigation bar where selection is made:

```
<div class="navBar">
        <a class="aNavBar" href="index.php">Home</a>     <a class="aNavBar" href="about.php">About</a>     <a class="aNavBar" href="galleries.php">Gallery</a>     <a class="aNavBar" href="equipment.php">Equipment</a>     <a class="aNavBar" href="links.php">Links</a>     <a class="aNavBar" href="contact.php">Contact</a>
    </div>

    <script>
       $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('.navBar a').click(function()
            {
                var href = $(this).attr('href'); //location.href;
                alert(href);
                $(this).addClass('selected');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I've tried putting code in the main (contact).php file, but the same thing is occurring.

Comment: This is the expected behaviour. DOM changes are not persisted between page loads. If you want to save state you would need to store the information somewhere (server database, localstorage, session, cookie etc) and then retrieve that state and apply it to each page you load in the future.

Comment: If you just want to highlight the menu item that links to the current page, you don’t need to store any “additional” info anywhere though - that info is already contained in $_SERVER. Go do some research please, this isn’t exactly a new topic. https://www.google.com/search?q=php+menu+highlight+current

Comment: A simple solution is usually to pass the selected menu (the clicked one), to the link that was clicked (as a get variable), and then set a CSS class on that menu item via PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do this in  following way

```
$path = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; // will return http://test.com/index.php for our example
$page = basename($path); // will return index.php
```

Then put condition

```
<a class=<?php ($page == index.php) ?  echo "aNavBar selected" : echo "aNavBar"; ?> href="index.php">Home</a>
```

Comment: Should the above code be in the navBar.php file? I tried it and it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes in navBar.php and please remove jquery code to add class over there. and please also check there your `$page` and you comparing with page return same values

Answer (score 0):

The links defined in html have standard colors, even when they are clicked or not. What defines if a link was clicked is the browser cache. As you are verified if it was selected, when the page loads this information will not be kept. It may be interesting to save the click of this link in the user's history, in a database, because through the browser it will not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, page state is not persisted after the page reloads or changes. So, you should not expect the selected hyperlink to remain 'selected' when the 2nd page is loaded. You can do it programatically though:

Something like this:

```
<div class="navBar">
    <a class="aNavBar<?php if(strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php')!==false) echo ' selected'; ?>" href="index.php">Home</a>     <a class="aNavBar" href="about.php<?php if(strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'about.php')!==false) echo ' selected'; ?>">About</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked:

```
  <?
            $path = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; // will return http://test.com/index.php for our example
            $page = basename($path); // will return index.php
        ?>
        <a class="aNavBar" <? if($page == "index.php") echo "style='color:red'";?> href="index.php">Home</a>
```

Thanks for your help!